# VBA Access IF condition

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem that my IF somehow doesn't validate good value of the field on index 0.

Here is the UDPATED code:

```
Private Sub Parametri()

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("ribe")


rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount
    If rs.Fields(i).Value > 2 Then

        Debug.Print rs.Fields("Lokacija_GS")
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
Next



End Sub
```

And here is the result:

```
1
43.626145
43.626145
43.630122
43.632358
43.625833
```

This value of "1" on index 0 should be skipped... but it isnt?

here is the table:

[image]

So for example if some row is 0 or 1 or NULL I want to skip it...

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code please? Without that this piece make very minimal sense.

Comment: If you could check now :)

Comment: Just curious, why do a `rs.MoveLast` `rs.MoveFirst` is it some kind of access trick?

Comment: I don't really know. Very new to VBA and I saw this kind of structure in most of the examples :D , was wondering the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code,

```
Private Sub Parametri()
    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("ribe")

    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("Lokacija_GS").Value > 2 Then _
            Debug.Print rs.Fields("Lokacija_GS")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark this as answer if it has solved your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Is it possible that I ask you a few more questions somehow ( skype or mail ) because I really am stuck on something or just need some guidelines and saw that you have some history in Access?